# Windows Docker container cannot talk to internet when Symantec endpoint protection is enabled

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-network, symantec

Windows 10 VM, docker version 20.10.5.
Create Windows docker container. I can ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
but curl [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) fails with unable to connect to remote server.

Disable Symmentec endpoint protection, everything works.
Did someone solved this? I cannot disable symmentec endpoint protection.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am getting the same and not able to disable SEP in my company laptop.

Comment: Not yet Sudeep. We are planning to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts. Hoping this will solve the problem.